# Different native queries to update database in a transaction

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, spring-data

I have 2 native queries which are being called in a @Transactional method, like this:

```
@Transactional
public void updateDatabaseWithNewRelease(NewRelease newRelease) {
    releaseGroupRepository.addReleaseGroupForTitle(newRelease.getTitle());
    releaseRepository.updateReleaseGroupId(newRelease.getTitle());
}
```

The first method does an insert into say table A, the second method reads from table A to to some update.

The issue I'm facing is that whatever insert was done in method 1 is not available in method 2.

Is there an issue with the way I'm using these 2 native queries to update the database?

Comment: If they are in the same transaction they can see each others data, but as you are using JPA (and not knowing what your methods are doing) you should probably do a flush somewhere to actually perform the SQL in the current transaciton.

Comment: Batch update are fetched immediatly. What can happen is that hibernate entities previously loaded have to be refreshed to take the first batch update into account. But if you second batch does not use previously loaded entities and cast a straight update request, that's not the problem. If you want to be sure of the sql request which are actually executed, set `show_sql=true` in your properties.